# onKeyDown is not being called

Tags: android

I want to handle the `navigation-bar` buttons.
I see that I can override the `onKeyDown()` method in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int code, KeyEvent e) {
if(code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    return true;
}else{
return super.onKeyDown(code, e);
}
}
```

But it is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

please add into Constructor

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocus();
```

Comment: They are both unresolved in the MainActivity.
Where should they be added?
Also, I use:   dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
to hide the navigation bar (and it is displayed only when it shows the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's getting called but you're not doing anything with it?

call `finish()` or something.

also you can override `onBackPressed()`

Comment: I have a break point inside, and the system doesn't call it.

Answer (score 0):

try to toast or log

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int code, KeyEvent e) {
    if (code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "on press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(code, e);
    }
}
```